# Up вектор в реализации камеры

Tags: c++, opengl

В примере к видовой матрице указано:

```
glm::mat4 View       = glm::lookAt(
glm::vec3(4,3,3), // Камера находится в мировых координатах (4,3,3)
glm::vec3(0,0,0), // И направлена в начало координат
glm::vec3(0,1,0)  // "Голова" находится сверху
);
```

Вопрос касательно 3го параметра. Разве `up` вектор, не должен указывать именно на точку над камерой (выше камеры)? 
Если у нас камера находиться в координатах `(4,3,3)`, тогда `up` должен быть `(4,4,3)`. Или нет?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ что значит "вектор из 0"?

Comment: в локальных координатах камеры

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/George_Chen41/publication/224198558/figure/fig8/AS:683198057029635@1539898518596/Camera-pose-The-position-vector-is-the-cameras-world-coordinates-The-orientation.jpg

Comment: @StrangerintheQ так на этом  изображении указано, что `up` выше самой камеры, а не в координатах `(0,1,0)` или вы имеете ввиду, что `(0,1,0)` это координаты относительно центра камеры, а не мира?

Comment: так точно, вектор на картинке отложен от центра камеры, вам уже ответили с формулой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже написали в комментариях, `up` задается относительно позиции камеры.

`up = точка_над_камерой - позиция_камеры = (4,4,3) - (4,3,3) = (0,1,0)`.

Answer (score 3):

Вы, очевидно, путаете термины *вектор* и *направленный отрезок*. Термин *вектор* соответствует всему классу направленных отрезков одинаковой длины и направления, а не какому-то конкретному отрезку. У вектора нет и не может быть конкретной позиции, т.е. он по определению никак не привязан и не может быть привязан ни к какой конкретной точке. В каком месте располагается ваша камера - не имеет никакого значения. В вашем случае речь идет о том, что направление "up" задается вектором `(0, 1, 0)`, ни больше, ни меньше.

Comment: как-то теперь точно запутался.. 
вектор это же и есть направленный отрезок.

Comment: @raviga Видимо имеется в виду, что у направленного отрезка есть конкретное положение в пространстве, а у вектора нет.